# Sum and stock size concurrent code using Executor

Tags: java, concurrency

The code should parse the input values and calculate the sum and size of particular stocks, using Executor thread pool by dynamically adding the thread count.

Please review the following code for calculating the sum of stocks and display the size of the stocks.

I'm not allowed to change the code after the comment:

> ```
> //DONT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW.
> ```

I know that read write lock is overkill as any way the threads are being terminated, but it doesn't seem to cause any harm. The only reason is that I want to lock the `arrayList` operations in the `putNewStock` method.

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.ReadLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock.WriteLock;

public class Stats {
    public static class StatisticsAggregatorImpl implements StatisticsAggregator {

        private ConcurrentHashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>> symbolPriceHash = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        private ReentrantReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

        private WriteLock writeLock = lock.writeLock();

        private ReadLock readLock = lock.readLock();

        @Override
        public void putNewPrice(String symbol, double price) {
            try {
                writeLock.lock();
                ArrayList<Double> array = symbolPriceHash.get(symbol);
                if (array == null) {
                    array = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    symbolPriceHash.put(symbol, array);
                }
                array.add(price);
            } finally {
                writeLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public double getAveragePrice(String symbol) {
            readLock.lock();
            try {
                return (symbolPriceHash.get(symbol)).stream()
                                                    .reduce(Double::sum)
                                                    .get();
            } finally {
                readLock.unlock();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getTickCount(String symbol) {
            readLock.lock();
            try {
                return (symbolPriceHash.get(symbol)).size();
            } finally {
                readLock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }

    ////////////////// DO NOT MODIFY BELOW THIS LINE ///////////////////

    public interface StatisticsAggregator {
        // This is an input. Make note of this price.
        public void putNewPrice(String symbol, double price);

        // Get the average price
        public double getAveragePrice(String symbol);

        // Get the total number of prices recorded
        public int getTickCount(String symbol);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            final StatisticsAggregator stats = new StatisticsAggregatorImpl();
            final Set<String> symbols = new TreeSet<>();

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] inputs = line.split(",");
            int threads = Integer.parseInt(inputs[0]);
            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
            for (int i = 1; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
                String[] tokens = inputs[i].split(" ");
                final String symbol = tokens[0];
                symbols.add(symbol);
                final double price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stats.putNewPrice(symbol, price);
                    }
                });

            }
            pool.shutdown();
            try {
                pool.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (String symbol : symbols) {
                System.out.println(
                        String.format("%s %.4f %d", symbol, stats.getAveragePrice(symbol), stats.getTickCount(symbol)));
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you are not allowed to change this code, what is the point in reviewing it? You wouldn't be able to implement any suggestions anyway :-|

Comment: As the dynamically created array list does not even get put back to the map, I sincerely doubt that this is working code.

Comment: yes forgot to put it in the hashMap sorry.

Comment: @ t3chb0t Actually it is interview question I'm suppose to implement the code above it.

Comment: have you even run this code? Attempting to get the tickCount for an unknown Symbol results in a`NullPointerException`. This also applies for getAverage. Also getAverage returns a sum for whatever reason???

Answer (score 1):

#### Java features:

Java introduced a nice shorthand to the if-condition you have in `putNewPrice`. It's `computeIfAbsent`. That reduces the method to the following:

```
try {
    writeLock.lock();
    symbolPriceHash.computeIfAbsent(symbol, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(price);
} finally {
    writeLock.unlock();
}
```

#### Rewritten using less wordy mechanisms

Since you're overkilling anyways, let's do just that and go to the nearly native locking mechanisms. After all you don't have to guarantee that the lock used is reentrant, right?

```
public static class StatisticsAggregatorImpl implements StatisticsAggregator {
    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ? extends List<Double>> symbolPrices = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void putNewPrice(String symbol, double price) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            symbolPrices.computeIfAbsent(symbol, new ArrayList<>()).add(price);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public double getAveragePrice(String symbol) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return symbolPrices.getOrDefault(symbol, Collections.emptyList())
              .stream()
              .average()
              .orElse(0.0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getTickCount(String symbol) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return symbolPrices.getOrDefault(symbol, Collections.emptyList()).size();
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation fixes the following bugs in your code:

- `getAverage` does not return an average, but a sum (dafuq?)
- `getTickCount` and `getAverage` throws a NullPointerException when an unknown symbol is checked

It also fixes the following bad habits:

- Naming things for what they are instead of what they mean. the `Hash` suffix is irrelevant for `symbolPrices`. It doesn't provide any useful semantic information and should be omitted.
- Overspecifying the type of collections in generics:
  Instead of specifying `ArrayList`, which is a specific collection type, this implementation specifies a Type-Bound enabling use of other Lists if necessary (or useful).
- Not explicitly making effectively final fields (and variables) final.